# Plotly 3d Python Enable Turntable rotation while animating

Tags: python, 3d, plotly, plotly-python

The Turntable interaction doesn't seem to work while my code is in the process of animation, but orbital rotation seems to work.
Here is what I am doing:

```
fig.add_trace(...) # adding spheres, lines, etc

# setting axis
fig.update_scenes(
        zaxis={
            'autorange': False,
            'range': [-100, 100],
        }
    )
    fig.update_scenes(
        xaxis={
            'autorange': False,
            'range': [-100, 100],
        }
    )
    fig.update_scenes(
        yaxis={
            'autorange': False,
            'range': [-100, 100],
        }
    )

# set modes
fig.layout.scene.aspectratio = {'x': 1, 'y': 1, 'z': 1}
fig.layout.uirevision = True
fig.layout.dragmode = "turntable"

fig.frames = [
            {
                'data': [go.Scatter3d(x=x, y=y, z=z, mode="lines", line=dict(dash='dot'))]
                'name': str(i),
                'traces': [2]
            }
    ... # more frames

] # set frames
```

How can I enable turntable interactions with 3d plotly? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a complete minimal example to copy-paste? Maybe just replace some data with dummy-data?